# boolean algebra Simplify solucion de la funcion

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Simplify the following expressions (Simplificar lo siguiente):

$$f= A'B'CD+A'BC'D+A'BCD'+AB'C'D+AB'CD'+ABC'D'$$

$$f=B'D(A'C+AC')+A'B(C'D+CD')+AD'(B'C+BC')$$

Comment: MSE is a site in English, so please don't use spanish when asking questions.